# Check Bandwidth Consumption

Tags: bandwidth

I have taken an hosting a/c with limited bandwidth. I have embedded a video tag (object)that links to youtube on my webpage.

I wanted to know that if someone views that video, will that be counted against my website bandwidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video hasn't magically moved itself to your host. If someone views the video, even if it's embedded on your page, the data is coming from YouTube.com.